# MySQL CONCAT without reading

Tags: mysql, performance, concatenation

I have a table which contains `MEDIUMTEXT` field for storing log.
I'm adding data to the log as follows:

```
UPDATE tbl SET log = CONCAT(log, 'newtext')
```

For short logs it works fine, but over time, as the log field gets bigger, it slows down exponentially. It seems that MySQL reads the whole field, then writes the whole thing back out.

How can I add data to the log without having troubles with performance? If there is no way to achieve this, how can I store and update such a big chunks of text data?

Answer (score 1):

If you think about this, it is quite obvious that the engine would:

```
1 - Retrieve the existing value of `log`,
2 - Concatenate the retrieved value with the new one,
3 - Store the result of "2" back in the same row.
```

(in practice, it performs this in a short-hand form)

Since (I'm guessing here) you would need the whole concatenate **only** when you wish to examine the log (which would take place with much lower frequency than that of adding information), I would recommend to store info in separate records (with a key column that would correspond to the specific ITEM on which you are collecting the logs) and make a concatenation only when needed (extraction).

You can even enhance this by having a DIGEST table that would store temporary concatenations (i.e. as created upon extraction) along with the index of the last entry included in the digest. Then, whenever you wish to view the "FULL STORY" of the item, you would extract first the digested text and then append whatever was registered AFTER the last digested value was recorded (and, of course, update the DIGEST table with the latest fully concatenated result).

Comment: It is worse than simply 1,2,3 -- the old row must be removed and space allocated for the new, bigger, row.

Comment: Not sure @RickJames that I understand your comment. The performance issue comes from the concatenation taking place in each INSERT. Under the assumption that there are very many INSERTS for each SELECT, the performance will definitely be improved by the proposed method (I have done this in the past, and improvement was VERY SIGNIFICANT). If I misunderstood you completely, please clarify.

Comment: Phrased differently - Step #3 is more costly than it appears on the surface.  Because of the storage (blocks for InnoDB, stream for MyISAM), the storing of the new, bigger, row can lead to a block split and other 'costly' actions under the covers.  (We are in agreement, and I like your answer.)

Comment: @RickJames, it is an honor for me to get approval from a person whose reputation is 25+ times mine. Thanks!!!

Comment: Keep up the good work.  It is nice to see answers where I don't feel the need to jump in and fix misconceptions.